# Search Button on Master Page Returns to Existing GridView on Separate Search Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'm looking to make a master page search return results to a GridView on another page, which also has a search button. I'd be grateful for any pointers on how to do this.... 
From Search Page .cs file. Following is Code on Search page and it's .cs page, search page button code, and master page search button code:

From Search Page .cs file:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=petsdat; UID=root; PASSWORD=; OPTION=3");
    MyConnection.Open();

    OdbcCommand MyCommand = MyConnection.CreateCommand();
    MyCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM pets WHERE species like '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'";

    OdbcDataReader MyDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();

    grdSearch.DataSource = MyDataReader;

    grdSearch.DataBind();

    MyConnection.Close();
}
```

From Search Page:

```
<form id="form2" >
    <div>
        <h1>Search for Pets</h1>
        <hr />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSearch" Text="Search"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSearch"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSearch" ErrorMessage="Try Again"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" PostBackUrl="~/Search.aspx" Text="Submit" />
        <br />
          <br />
           <br />
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdSearch" BorderColor="#CC6600" 
            BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" 
            GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Left"   Width="600px"></asp:GridView>
        <br />

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Master Page Search Submit Button Code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Search1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" PostBackUrl="~/Search.aspx" />
```

Comment: You really want to execute a search-command on every postback of your master page? That would mean that every postback of any page in your application will be a search-request. Instead use event handlers(`SearchBtn-Click event`[rename your `Button1` for reasons of readability]).

Answer (score 1):

On Button1 Click event you can set the value of Search1 (TextBox) in QueryString & the do a redirect to your Search Page.

Eg.:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("~/Search.aspx?SearchText=" + Search1.Text);        
}
```

Also, you have to modify the Search Page Code:

```
string searchText = "";
if(Request.QueryString["SearchText"] != null)
  searchText = Request.QueryString["SearchText"];
MyCommand.CommandText = 
          "SELECT * FROM pets WHERE species like '%" + searchText  + "%'";
```

Comment: Thank you. It connects to the search page but it doesn't actually do a search. It only triggers a search error message like "try again."